# Data From Svc Not Modeling Into View Elements AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a view that is modeled to functions which pass data through to a database. This is all working and I see the data coming back when called, but it is not pre-populating the fields in my view when it comes back. I've been banging my head for a while on this. Everything is modeled (from what I can tell) properly.

I have stepped through the JS code below in Chrome and see the data being assigned to my $scope variables from the data.XXX return.

But, after load finishes, it's not preselecting my radio button or populating the fields with the data. Any help greatly appreciated.

Here is the View:

```
<div class="notification-container">
        <form name="notificationForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="saveQrNotifications()">
        <div class="list-unstyled">
            <input id="text" ng-model="NotificationMethods.NotificationMethodId" ng-change="notifyVisible()" name="text" type="radio" ng-value="1001"> Text Message<br>
            <input id="email" ng-model="NotificationMethods.NotificationMethodId" ng-change="notifyVisible()" name="email" type="radio" ng-value="6"> Email<br>
            <input id="voice" ng-model="NotificationMethods.NotificationMethodId" ng-change="notifyVisible()" name="voice" type="radio" ng-value="1003"> Voice<br>
            <input id="nocontact" ng-model="NotificationMethods.NotificationMethodId" ng-change="notifyVisible()" name="nocontact" type="radio" ng-value="1000"> Do Not Contact<br>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 notification-fields" ng-show="notifyFieldVisibility == true">
             <div class="col-md-12" ng-if="NotificationMethods.NotificationMethodId == '1001'">
                <label class="notication-input">Text Number</label>
                    <span class="clearfix"></span>
                    <input class="form-control area-code" type="text" ng-model="NotificationMethods.NotificationTextAreaCode" placeholder="(555)" required>
                    <input class="form-control phone-number" type="text" ng-model="NotificationMethods.NotificationTextPhoneNumber" placeholder="555-5555" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" ng-if="NotificationMethods.NotificationMethodId == '6'">
                <label class="notification-input" for="email">E-mail Address
                    <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="text" ng-model="NotificationMethods.NotificationEmailAddress" placeholder="ex.me@example.com" required>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" ng-if="NotificationMethods.NotificationMethodId == '1003'">
                <label class="notication-input">Voice Number </label>
                <span class="clearfix"></span>
                    <input class="form-control area-code" type="text" ng-model="NotificationMethods.NotificationVoiceAreaCode" placeholder="(555)" required>
                    <input class="form-control phone-number" type="text" ng-model="NotificationMethods.NotificationVoicePhoneNumber" placeholder="555.5555" required>
                <label class="small">Ext.</label>
                <input class="form-control extension" type="text" ng-model="NotificationMethods.NotificationVoiceExtension" placeholder="555">
            </div>
            <span class="clearfix"></span>
            <div ng-show="notifyLoading" class="text-center" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Saving...
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary notification-btn">Save Notifications</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        </form>

</div>
```

Here is my controller:

DATA COMING FROM DB:

```
if (data.StatusCode == "SUCCESS") {
            $scope.refill = data;
            //$scope.deliverTypes = data.DeliveryTypes;
            $scope.showError = false;
            $scope.submitRefill = true;
            $scope.findRefillStatus = userMessageService.QuickRefillMessage(data.Prescriptions[0]);
            $scope.isRefillable = data.Prescriptions[0].IsRefillable;
            $scope.prescription.noPrescription.$valid = true;
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.NotificationMethods.NotificationEmailAddress = data.NotificationEmailAddress;
            $scope.NotificationMethods.NotificationMethodId = data.NotificationMethodId;
            $scope.NotificationMethods.NotificationTextAreaCode = data.NotificationTextAreaCode;
            $scope.NotificationMethods.NotificationTextPhoneNumber = data.NotificationTextPhoneNumber;
            $scope.NotificationMethods.NotificationVoiceAreaCode = data.NotificationVoiceAreaCode;
            $scope.NotificationMethods.NotificationVoicePhoneNumber = data.NotificationVoicePhoneNumber;
            $scope.NotificationMethods.NotificationVoiceExtension = data.NotificationVoiceExtension;
        }
```

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle?

Comment: It will take a bit, I really just pulled the action elements for this piece to display above, there's quite a bit involved for ng-if/show elements that I'll have to refactor for jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was declaring the controller on the view used in ng-include. Removing that and letting the view inherit controller from surrounding view solved issue.